# JPA Entity Graph with entity manager getResultList() method return list of entity in any type in response

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Father.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ClinicManagementVariableUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_FATHER)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)

@NamedQueries({ 
        @NamedQuery(name = "father.findAll", query = "SELECT f FROM Father f") 
})

@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "graph.father.setOfChildrens", 
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "setOfChildrens")),
    })
})
public class Father {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "fatherId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "firstName", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "degree", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
    private String degree;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "father")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Mother mother;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father") // children
    private Set<Children> setOfChildrens;

    getter()
    setter()
}
```

**Children.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ClinicManagementVariableUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_CHILDREN)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Children {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "childrenId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Father father;

    getter()
    setter()
}
```

**Mother.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ClinicManagementVariableUtils.TABLE_NAME_FOR_MOTHER)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Mother {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "motherId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "varchar(50)", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fatherId")
    private Father father;

    getter()
    setter()
}
```

**FatherDao.java**

```
public interface FatherDao extends GenericModelDao<Father> {

    // Note : Return type is Mother instead of Father
    public List<Mother> getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph();
}
```

**FatherDaoImpl.java**

```
@Named
public class FatherDaoImpl extends GenericModelDaoImpl<Father> implements FatherDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Mother> getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph() {
        EntityGraph graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("graph.father.setOfChilrensAndAddresses");

        List<Mother> list = entityManager.createNamedQuery("father.findAll").setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph)
                .getResultList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

**FatherService.java**

```
public interface FatherService {

    // Note : Return type is Mother instead of Father
    public List<Mother> getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph();
}
```

**FatherServiceImpl.java**

```
@Named
public class FatherServiceImpl implements FatherService {

    @Inject
    private FatherDao fatherDao;

    @Override
    public List<Mother> getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph() {
        return fatherDao.getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph();
    }

}
```

**FatherController.java**

```
@Controller
public class FatherController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FatherController.class);

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Mother> getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph() {
        List<Mother> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            // Note : now list of father object is return as list of mother but it working..
            list =  fatherService.getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

In `Father.java`, there are 2 type of annotations:

- Native Query
- Entity Graph

Now in DAO layer, I execute native query with graph query in `getFathersUsingNativeQueryAndEntityGraph()` method which will return list of fathers.

But when I fetch it in `List<Mother>` then also it returns all fields from `Father.java` even if those fields not exists in `Mother.java`.

Doubt:
If it returns all Fields of `Father.java` then how it is possible that it returns response in `Mother.java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Since you have no type checks anywhere this code will always compile.**

**2. As long as you never access an object in that list specifically as a `Mother` object, your code will run.**

When you use `createNamedQuery` without a class parameter, you create an untyped `Query` object, which returns a **raw list** with whatever objects JPA returns.

In your code this list will contain `Father` objects, because that is what you asked for.

Writing `List<Mother> list = ...` is wrong, but your compiler doesn't know this. Since the type parameter is only checked **at compile time**, this code will run and during **runtime** `list` will be a generic list holding `Father` objects.

You should get a compiler **warning** here about turning that generic list into a `List<Mother>`, because the compiler cannot guarantee that this is correct. Listen to such warnings, they are there for a reason.

Only when you do this:

```
Mother mother = list.get(0);
```

will you get a **runtime error**, specifically a `ClassCastException`. However, **your compiler will not complain about this**, because it believes your list will contain `Mother` objects, because you lied to it above.

**Fix your code**

You should use a `TypedQuery` instead, by passing the class you expect to `createNamedQuery`:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("father.findAll", Father.class)
```

This will enforce the correct type during **compile time**, so doing `List<Mother> list = ...` will not compile anymore.

Comment: I like the way you explained.